# Why can I std::bind successfully with the wrong parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdbind

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using callback = std::function<void(int, void*)>;

void AddCallback(callback cb) {}

void foo(int i) {}

int main() {
  auto f = std::bind(&foo, std::placeholders::_1);
  AddCallback(f);
}
```

I tried the code with g++ 9.3.0 and clang++ 10.0.0, they both compiled ends no errors.

Is the type of bind result and callback the same type? One is `std::function<void(int, void*)>`, the other is something equal to `std::function<void(int)>`?  Why can I call `AddCallback()` with different types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you can pass more arguments to the result of `bind` than necessary, and they will be silently ignored.

> If some of the arguments that are supplied in the call to [the result of `bind`] are not matched by any placeholders ..., the unused arguments are evaluated and discarded.
>
> — [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

Comment: Is the type of bind result and callback the same type? why can I call AddCallback() with different types? One is std::function<void(int, void*)>, the other is something equal to std::function<void(int)>?

Comment: @Xingx1 Because `std::function` can be constructed from any callable that you can call with the specified arguments. If you can call the result of `std::bind` using the arguments of the specified types, it can be converted to a `std::function`.

Comment: The result of `std::bind` is a type with a templated `operator()`. It **isn't** an instantiation of `std::function`, rather `std::function<void(int, void*)>` has a converting constructor that accepts the binder type

Answer (score 0):

it's not your AddCallback() whose accepting differnt type but it's type deduction whose creating confusing;

for example try to use

```
std::function<void(int)> f = std::bind(&foo, std::placeholders::_1);
```

or Addcallback function we will give you error

> Error (active)    E0312   no suitable user-defined conversion from
> "std::function<void (int)>" to "callback" exists

Comment: The problem is that result of `std::bind` call is not `std::function`, it's an unspecified type that can be converted to `std::function`. If you changed type of `f` to `std::function<void(int, void*)>`, it would compile perfectly.

Comment: That's true. That type of std::bind is unspecified but his question is "Why can I call AddCallback() with different types?"